# Can't create a database link for CMS WebGUI

Tags: sql-server, linux, perl, freetds, unixodbc

I've updated the whole scenario (last one was a conflict between i686 and x64 libraries)

Now I have an VPS with a fresh CentOS 6.6 32 bit with unixODBC, FreeTDS and WebGUI installed

I can connect perfectly with SQL Server 2008 through isql and perl scripts.

BUT my goal is to create a database link for WebGUI (an open-source CMS based in perl)

Output for `odbcinst -j`

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 4
SQLLEN Size........: 4
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 2
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=v0.95.73
Driver=/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0.0.0
UsageCount=1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[DSN]
Description=DNS description
Driver=FreeTDS
Server=XX.XX.XX.XX
Database=myDatabase
Port=1433 #sql server default port
TDS_Version=7.3
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/sql.log
```

When I execute this perl script, it runs ok.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;

my $dsn = "DBI:ODBC:DSN"; # Same DSN as above
my $db_user = "dbuser";
my $db_pass = 'dbpass';
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass) or die "$DBI::errstr\n";
print "Connected\n";
my $query = "Select * from myTable";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "$DBI::errstr\n";
$sth->execute or die "$DBI::errstr\n";
# go do stuff!
# Close the database
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

This is the database link I'm trying to add to WebGUI
[image: Adding a database link in WebGUI]

When I commit the changes, I get this error in my browser:

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /home.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

modproxy.error.log

```
[Wed Dec 23 14:15:42 2015] [error] [client IP] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /home, referer: http://VPSIP/home?op=editDatabaseLink;dlid=y2Yf1_oEJD6-Wm-T-yHy-w
[Wed Dec 23 14:15:58 2015] [error] [client IP] (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8081, referer: http://VPSIP/home?op=editDatabaseLink;dlid=y2Yf1_oEJD6-Wm-T-yHy-w
[Wed Dec 23 14:15:58 2015] [error] [client IP] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /home, referer: http://VPSIP/home?op=editDatabaseLink;dlid=y2Yf1_oEJD6-Wm-T-yHy-w
```

modperl.error.log

```
[Wed Dec 23 14:15:59 2015] [notice] child pid 7766 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Maybe WebGUI is trying to load the /home from SQL Server instead of mysql? (I just want to connect to SQL Server to fetch some products, nothing else)

Any help would be appreciated
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just added

```
use DBD::ODBC;
```

to the file SQL.pm and WebGUI is able to recognize unixODBC (and FreeTDS, too).

Merry X'Mas!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

[Source](http://mailman.unixodbc.org/pipermail/unixodbc-support/2011-November/003022.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your `odbc.ini`, you specify the DRIVER defined in `odbcinst.ini`.

Try this for `odbc.ini`:

```
[DSN]
Description=DNS description
Driver=FreeTDS
Server=XX.XX.XX.XX
Database=myDatabase
Port=1433 #sql server default port
TDS_Version=7.3
```

Also, be sure you use the right TDS Version for the SQL Server version and FreeTDS version you're using. I'd recommend sticking with 7.2 unless you need 7.3: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm I've got example `odbc.ini`, `odbcinst.ini` and `freetds.conf` files in this repo, if they help: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant/tree/master/examples

Good luck!